# Pasrse.com Image not showing on UIImage?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

My code seems to be right. I am saving image to User column named **profileImage** on **Parse.com**. The user image saves fine, but I cannot get it to display in a `UIImageView`. My code has no errors. Been stuck on this for awhile.

```
import UIKit 
import Parse 
import Bolts 
import ParseUI

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var previewImage: PFImageView!
@IBOutlet var finalImage: UIImageView! = UIImageView()

@IBOutlet weak var savedImage: PFImageView!
var image = [PFFile]()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func chooseTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.PhotoLibrary)!
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false;



    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)



}





func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    self.previewImage.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)



}


@IBAction func upload(sender: AnyObject) {

    let imageToBeUploaded = self.previewImage.image
    let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToBeUploaded!,1.0)!


    let file: PFFile = PFFile(data: imageData)!
    let photoToUpload = PFObject(className: "profileImage")
    //try! photoToUpload.save()

    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    user!.setObject(photoToUpload, forKey: "profilePicture")
    user?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success: Bool! ,error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (success != nil) {

            print("saving")




        }
    }

}

func displayImage()
{
    if let userPicture = PFUser.currentUser()?["profilePicture"] as? PFFile {
        userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {


                self.previewImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
            }
        }

    }}




/*func postProfileImage(){

    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    let profileImage:PFFile = user!["profileImage"] as! PFFile

    profileImage.getDataInBackground()
   let savedimage = profileImage




}*/




/*@IBAction func uploadImage(sender: AnyObject) {


    let imageToBeUploaded = self.previewImage.image
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToBeUploaded!)

    let file: PFFile = PFFile(data: imageData!)!
    let photoToUpload = PFObject(className: "profileImage")

  try!     photoToUpload.save()



}*/



/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: You don't do anything if error isn't nil in `displayImage`. Perhaps you are getting an error there?

Comment: There is also conditional unwrapping in the method, so have you set a breakpoint and stepped through to see what is happening?

Comment: Okay thanks. Ill try that.